# How to have dropdown data WHERE we get from other table for the editing data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to have the same drop down Hardware_ID in Adding new record form WHERE I get the data from another table for my Update form.

This is the example for my Update (Edit) form. 
[Update Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rKNL.png)

And this is my Adding new record form. 
[Adding new record Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10DES.png)

this is my code for Update Form. Im using the same code like my adding new record but I got an error(The error is in the Update Form).

```
<?php

//get the data
$Asset_ID = $_GET['Asset_ID'];
$Hardware_ID = $_GET['Hardware_ID'];
$Vendor_ID = $_GET['Vendor_ID'];
$PO_ID = $_GET['PO_ID'];


?>

<form action = 'Update_Asset2_Process.php' method = 'POST'>
<table border = '1' align = 'center' cellspacing='0'   cellpadding='10'    
 bgcolor = "White">
 <tr>
   <th colspan = '2'>ASSET UPDATE FORM</th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
     <td align='center'>Asset ID :</td>
     <td><input type = "varchar" name = "Asset_ID" value = "<?php echo 
          $Asset_ID; ?>" readonly></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td align='center'> Hardware ID: </td>
   <td><input type = "varchar" name = "Hardware_ID" value = "<?php echo 
    $Hardware_ID?>">

    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM hardware2 ORDER BY Hardware_ID";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) 
    {
        while ($id = mysql_fetch_row($result))

            {
                echo "<option value='" . $id[0] . "'>" . $id[0] . " : " . 
                $id[1] . " </option>";
            }

    }
?>
    </select> 


</tr>



 <tr>
    <td align='center'>Vendor ID :</td>
    <td><input type = "varchar" name = "Vendor_ID" value = "<?php echo 
     $Vendor_ID; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align='center'>PO ID :</td>
   <td><input type = "varchar" name = "PO_ID" value = "<?php echo $PO_ID; ?
   >"></td>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan = '2' align = 'right'>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'UPDATE'>
</td>
 </tr>
<a href = "View_Asset2.php">Back to Asset</a>
</table>
</form>
```

thanks for your help, Regards

Comment: Have you fire this query into the database directly? Because seems not issue with query. Also could not see database connection here.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong select box syntax

```
<?php
//get the data
$Asset_ID    = isset($_GET['Asset_ID']) ? $_GET['Asset_ID'] : 0;
$Hardware_ID = isset($_GET['Hardware_ID']) ? $_GET['Hardware_ID'] : 0;
$Vendor_ID   = isset($_GET['Vendor_ID']) ? $_GET['Vendor_ID'] : 0;
$PO_ID       = isset($_GET['PO_ID']) ? $_GET['PO_ID'] : 0;
?>

<form action = 'Update_Asset2_Process.php' method = 'POST'>
<table border = '1' align = 'center' cellspacing='0'   cellpadding='10' bgcolor = "White">
 <tr>
   <th colspan = '2'>ASSET UPDATE FORM</th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
     <td align='center'>Asset ID :</td>
     <td><input type = "varchar" name = "Asset_ID" value = "<?php echo $Asset_ID; ?>" readonly></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td align='center'> Hardware ID: </td>
   <td><input type = "varchar" name = "Hardware_ID" value = "<?php echo $Hardware_ID?>">

    <select id="Your_id" name="Your_name">
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM hardware2 ORDER BY Hardware_ID";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) 
    {
        while ($id = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            echo "<option value='".$id[0]."'>".$id[0]." : ".$id[1]."</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select> 
</tr>

 <tr>
    <td align='center'>Vendor ID :</td>
    <td><input type = "varchar" name = "Vendor_ID" value = "<?php echo $Vendor_ID; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align='center'>PO ID :</td>
   <td><input type = "varchar" name = "PO_ID" value = "<?php echo $PO_ID; ?>" /></td>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan = '2' align = 'right'>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'UPDATE'>
</td>
 </tr>
<a href = "View_Asset2.php">Back to Asset</a>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe no need the select box in this form

```
<?php
//get the data
$Asset_ID    = isset($_GET['Asset_ID']) ? $_GET['Asset_ID'] : 0;
$Hardware_ID = isset($_GET['Hardware_ID']) ? $_GET['Hardware_ID'] : 0;
$Vendor_ID   = isset($_GET['Vendor_ID']) ? $_GET['Vendor_ID'] : 0;
$PO_ID       = isset($_GET['PO_ID']) ? $_GET['PO_ID'] : 0;
?>

<form action = 'Update_Asset2_Process.php' method = 'POST'>
<table border = '1' align = 'center' cellspacing='0'   cellpadding='10' bgcolor = "White">
 <tr>
   <th colspan = '2'>ASSET UPDATE FORM</th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
     <td align='center'>Asset ID :</td>
     <td><input type = "varchar" name = "Asset_ID" value = "<?php echo $Asset_ID; ?>" readonly></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td align='center'> Hardware ID: </td>
   <td><input type = "varchar" name = "Hardware_ID" value = "<?php echo $Hardware_ID?>">
</tr>

 <tr>
    <td align='center'>Vendor ID :</td>
    <td><input type = "varchar" name = "Vendor_ID" value = "<?php echo $Vendor_ID; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align='center'>PO ID :</td>
   <td><input type = "varchar" name = "PO_ID" value = "<?php echo $PO_ID; ?>" /></td>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan = '2' align = 'right'>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'UPDATE'>
</td>
 </tr>
<a href = "View_Asset2.php">Back to Asset</a>
</table>
</form>
```